# LoopBack API - Built-in Models and Persistence

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, strongloop, loopback

I want to build an API, using Google auth (via the loopback-component-passport) and ACL for access control. I also need to extend the standard User model, as I have some additional data fields.

By default the `User`, `AccessToken`, `ACL`, `RoleMapping` and `Role` models use the in-memory storage, i.e. data will be lost once the app restarts. So, my questions are:

1. To persist data to MySQL, I would need to `automigrate` these models from in-memory to MySQL data source. But, if I'm going to extend the `User` model as `StaffUser`, do I need to have tables for both `User` and `StaffUser` in the DB? Or, do I then keep `User` in-memory and `StaffUser` in MySQL?
2. The passport component adds its own models (`UserIdentity`, `UserCredential`, `ApplicationCredential`,`PassportConfigurator`). Would there be any reason to persist these in MySQL, or do I keep these in-memory?

Answer (score 0):

> To persist data to MySQL, I would need to automigrate these models from in-memory to MySQL data source. But, if I'm going to extend the User model as StaffUser, do I need to have tables for both User and StaffUser in the DB? Or, do I then keep User in-memory and StaffUser in MySQL?

I don't think you would need to auto-migrate these models from in-memory to your data source. Instead, you should just change the dataSource property of the model in your app's [model-config.json](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/model-config.json) from the default in-memory to the data source defined by you. If your app uses only `StaffUser` and doesn't need `User`, you may not need to put User in MySQL.

> The passport component adds its own models (UserIdentity, UserCredential, ApplicationCredential,PassportConfigurator). Would there be any reason to persist these in MySQL, or do I keep these in-memory?

The section "Connectors" in this [Strongloop article](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Connecting+models+to+data+sources) says that the in-memory data source is suitable only for development and debugging purposes. We shouldn't let the login related information lie in-memory and let them get wiped out in an app restart.